# How to DELETE/INSERT rows in the same table using a UPDATE Trigger?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.6

I want to create a trigger function, which copies certain columns of an recent updated row and deletes the old data. After that I want to insert the copied columns in exact the same table in the same row (overwrite).  I need the data to be INSERTED because this function will be embedded in an existing program, with predefined Triggers.

That's what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN

WITH tmp AS (DELETE FROM table 
             WHERE table.id = NEW.id 
             RETURNING id, geom ) 

INSERT INTO table (id, geom) SELECT * FROM tmp;

                  
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;

 
CREATE TRIGGER T_update
AFTER UPDATE OF geom ON table
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_table();
```

But I get the Error message:

> ERROR:  cannot perform DELETE RETURNING on relation "table" 
> HINT:  You need an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule with a RETURNING clause.

Why I should use a rule here?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6

UPDATE:

A little bit of clarification. When I have two columns in my table (`id, geom`), after I updated `geom` I want to make a copy of this (new)row and insert it into the same table, while overwriting the updated row. (I'm not interested in any value before the update) I know that this is odd but I need this row to be inserted again because the program i embed this function in, listens to a `INSERT` statement and cannot be changed by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thanks to @JimJones for the answer. I´d like to post his answer modified for this purpose. This code "overwrites" the updated row by inserting a copy of itself and then deleting the old duplicate. That way I can Trigger on `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TABLE t (Unique_id SERIAL,id int, geom geometry(point,4326));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t (id, geom) VALUES (NEW.id,NEW.geom);
  RETURN NEW;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_update 
BEFORE UPDATE OF geom ON t FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_table();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM t a
    USING t b
    WHERE a.Unique_id < b.Unique_id
    AND a.geom = b.geom;
RETURN NEW;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_delete 
AFTER UPDATE OF geom ON t FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_table();


INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,1,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)');


UPDATE t SET geom = 'SRID=4326;POINT(2 2)' WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Right after you update a row, its old values will no longer be available. So, if you simply want to preserve the old row in case of an update you need to create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, so that you can still access the `OLD` values and create a new row, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, geom geometry(point,4326));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t (id, geom) VALUES (OLD.id,OLD.geom);
  RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER t_update 
BEFORE UPDATE OF geom ON t FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_table();

INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)');
```

If you update the record `1` ..

```
UPDATE t SET geom = 'SRID=4326;POINT(2 2)', id = 2 WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE t SET geom = 'SRID=4326;POINT(3 3)', id = 3 WHERE id = 2;
```

.. you get a new record in the same table as you wished

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) FROM t;

 id | st_astext  
----+------------
  1 | POINT(1 1)
  2 | POINT(2 2)
  3 | POINT(3 3)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=03363158d5b0f7f2a1d945183b52d13a)

Unrelated note: consider upgrading your PostgreSQL version! 9.6 will reach EOL in November, 2021.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please check my Update!

Comment: @DrSnuggles have you tried `(NEW.id,NEW.geom);` instead of `(OLD.id,OLD.geom);` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ea12409ec86fa6a8bf4e97a16e23f254